# Keypoints morphing

Tags: morphing

Is there a library/software which can accept a number of keypoints and matches of them between images and produce a morph? Or any ideas/algorithms on how to do it?

Comment: Are you looking for answers that are related to one specific programming language, or is this question intended to be language-agnostic?

Answer (score 1):

[Xmorph and GTK morph](http://xmorph.sourceforge.net/) can do that -- although the key points must be parts of equivalent rectangle grids. The underlying algorithm can be accessed through a C API.

Answer (score 0):

An older piece of software by [Gryphon Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gryphon_Software_Morph) could do image morphing. I saw an article about it from 1994. I couldn't find a company site, so they may be abandon ware now.

Her is a quote from a Wikipedia article about a film editing [technique called Dissolve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissolve_(film)).

> In non-linear video editing, a dissolve is done in software, by interpolating gradually between the RGB values of each pixel of the image.

Hope that helps.